# Partial view using a ViewModel which inherits from another class doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, viewmodel, partial-views

I have a view model for a view which displays multiple forms on the same page. This view model contains 'sub-view-models' for each form that will be rendered. Each form has it's own PartialView.

All of these forms share a set of properties (contact info), yet each form has a distinct set of additional properties. So I thought it made sense for each of these form classes to inherit from a base class. However, when I attempt to access the url, I get the following error.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'MyProject.ViewModels.JobForm', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'MyProject.ViewModels.NightShiftForm'.

**Main View**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
  Inherits="ViewUserControl<MyProject.ViewModels.JobsViewModel>" %>

<%: Html.Partial("_NightShiftForm", Model.NightShiftForm) %>
<%: Html.Partial("_DayShiftForm", Model.DayShiftForm) %>
```

**Partial View for '_NightShiftForm'**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
  Inherits="ViewUserControl<MyProject.ViewModels.NightShiftForm>" %>
```

**View Model & Form Classes**

```
public class JobsViewModel {
  public NightShiftForm NightShiftForm { get; set; }
  public DayShiftForm DayShiftForm { get; set; }
}

public class JobForm {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class DayShiftForm : JobForm {
  public string PreferredCoffeeBrand { get; set; }
  public bool IsMorningPerson { get; set; }
}

public class NightShiftForm : JobForm {
  public string PreferredLocation { get; set; }
  public string PreferredNights { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I suspect that the 2 properties in your `JobsViewModel` are of type `JobForm` and not as you have shown in your question here `NightShiftForm` and `DayShiftForm`. What you have shown in your question should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that MVC has a hard time when you pass null values as the model parameter to `Html.RenderPartial`. My fix looks like the following:

```
public class JobsViewModel {
  public NightShiftForm NightShiftForm { get; set; }
  public DayShiftForm DayShiftForm { get; set; }

  public JobsViewModel() {
    NightShiftForm = new NightShiftForm();
    DayShiftForm = new DayShiftForm();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes... I have also encountered problems when passing in a null model to RenderPartial()... MVC seems to look for the type of the parent. This is indeed the solution here - make sure that the model (or sub-model) is instantiated.